# Inconsistent Timestamp format when merging to dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge, timestamp

I am merging two dataframes, both have a Timestamp format DD.MM.YYYY. But when I merge them, some rows have format MM.DD.YYYY and others DD.MM.YYYY.

The dataframes I'm using are being exported from csv files and are really big, but here's an example:

df_dts1:

```
dict = {'date' : ['01.07.2022 00:01:00', '24.07.2022 22:46:00', '09.08.2022 15:14:00', '06.09.2022 18:45:00'],
'CST_dts_eCO2_FC_out_SGP30' : [469, 1167, 5638, 651],
'CST_dts_IAQ_FC_in_BME680' : [196, 39, 25, 186],
'CST_dts_eCO2_FC_out_BME680' : [891, 12690, 6238, 1701]}

df_dts1 = pd.DataFrame(dict)
display(df_dts1)
```

| date | CST_dts_eCO2_FC_out_SGP30 | CST_dts_IAQ_FC_in_BME680 | CST_dts_eCO2_FC_out_BME680 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.07.2022 00:01:00 | 469 | 196 | 891 |
| 24.07.2022 22:46:00 | 1167 | 39 | 12690 |
| 09.08.2022 15:14:00 | 5638 | 25 | 6238 |
| 06.09.2022 18:45:00 | 651 | 186 | 1701 |

df_OxyMode:

```
dict = {'LOCALTIME' : ['01.07.2022 02:00:04', '20.08.2022 02:00:09', '02.09.2022 02:00:39', '01.10.2022 01:59:56'],
'x_LowOxyRegeneration_SPS' : [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]}

df_OxyMode = pd.DataFrame(dict)
display(df_OxyMode)
```

| LOCALTIME | x_LowOxyRegeneration_SPS |
| --- | --- |
| 01.07.2022 02:00:04 | 0.0 |
| 20.08.2022 02:00:09 | 0.0 |
| 02.09.2022 02:00:39 | 1.0 |
| 01.10.2022 01:59:56 | 0.0 |

I am currently trying this:

```
frames = [df_dts1, df_OxyMode]

# rename columns to have same name
df_dts1.rename(columns={'date':'Timestamp'}, inplace=True)
df_OxyMode.rename(columns={'LOCALTIME':'Timestamp'}, inplace=True)

# datetime format to avoid error (incompatible merge keys [0] dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O'), must be the same type)
df_dts1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dts1['Timestamp'])
df_OxyMode['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_OxyMode['Timestamp'])

# sorting to avoid error (ValueError: left keys must be sorted)
df_dts1 = df_dts1.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=True)
df_OxyMode = df_OxyMode.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=True)

# merge dfs 
df_ausw = pd.merge_asof(df_dts1, df_OxyMode, on='Timestamp').assign(Timestamp = lambda x: x['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'))
df_ausw = df_ausw.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=True)

display(df_ausw)
```

but the format of the Timestamp column is inconsistent (some rows MM.DD.YYYY and others DD.MM.YYYY) and looks like this:
[merged df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7maHQ.png)

At first I had it without the

> .assign(Timestamp = lambda x: x['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'))

but when I plotted the data it looked wrong:
[merged df without .assign(Timestamp = lambda...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcoPB.png)
instead of:
[df before merging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I74dm.png)

Does someone have any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Force the format in `pd.to_datetime` with `format='%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @mozway, but sadly it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Then please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: If you do not specify a format for `pd.to_datetime`, it will assume the month is listed first. That does not seem to be true for your input. So use e.g. `pd.to_datetime(df_dts1['Timestamp'], dayfirst=True)`.

Comment: @mozway I tried again and it worked :) I just had to put also the time format. Thanks!

Comment: @FObersteiner I also tried your suggestion and it worked instantely, thank you!

Comment: I also had the problem that the dates where not being sorted out correctly. But the problem got solved by adding `df_asw.sort_index(inplace=True)`